# MYSQL - Left joins, optimize 2 sec query

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

I try to optimize my MySQL query, I merged already all tables to one table where it seems useful.

But the query still takes over 2 seconds... Is there a way to make it faster?

On user_id is always an index. MySQL 5.5.12, all tables except cities are InnoDB tables.

```
SELECT b.user_id,b.firstname,b.lastname,b.address,b.zipcode,b.city
  , ($calculatings) AS Distance
FROM `user_profiles` `b`
LEFT JOIN `cities` `a` ON `a`.`postal`=`b`.`zipcode` 
JOIN `users` `u` ON `b`.`user_id`=`u`.`id` 
JOIN `user_consultants` `c` ON `b`.`user_id`=`c`.`user_id` 
WHERE ($calculatings) <= 25 
      AND c.incorporated='1' 
      AND u.typ='1' 
      AND u.activated='1' 
      AND u.banned='0' 
ORDER BY Distance ASC, c.zsum_score DESC 
LIMIT 30
```

In the var $calculatings are the math operations for the distance calculation (already optimized).

$calculatings example:

```
6368 * SQRT(2*(1-cos(RADIANS(`a`.`lat`)) * cos(0.840105508801) * 
(sin(RADIANS(`a`.`lon`)) * sin(0.201952047748) + cos(RADIANS(`a`.`lon`)) * 
cos(0.201952047748)) - sin(RADIANS(`a`.`lat`)) * sin(0.840105508801)))
```

**Why so many Left Joins?**

1. user_profiles is the detail_table of the user informations
2. cities is the city table with all cities of my country with lat and lon and more informations
3. users is the main user table for username & password, hashes, login tries, bans etc...
4. user_consultants is an additional table for a special group of users

**Sizes**

1. user_profiles 112.000 rows
2. cities 68.000 rows
3. users 246.000 rows
4. user_consultants 98.000 rows

**Explain SQL**
[image] (Rightclick for fullsize)

Comment: *«I merged already all tables to one table where it seems useful.»* Having one huge table instead of several smaller ones does not necessarily improve performance. I suggest you run an `EXPLAIN SQL ...` query and post the result here.

Comment: In addition to above comment, make sure you've tuned your InnoDB settings since the ones out of the box aren't really good if you expect performance.

Comment: I'd like to answer, but all those backticks are giving me a headache.

Comment: It would still be useful to see the source of `$calculatings`

Comment: I guess the `$calculatings` come from `cities  (a)` so the `LEFT JOIN cities` is actually an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: The other 2 `LEFT JOIN` are also (obviously) cancelled.

Comment: I added now the $calculatings var.

Comment: @heuri ypercube is right. Your query should work the same without LEFT joins.

Comment: First thank you very much for all your answers, I will try it now without the LEFT joins.

Comment: Are slowing maybe the foreign keys (incorporated, user_id) the query down? I'm working the first time with the new InnoDB at mysql 5.5. I have a smilar query who just needs 0,2 sec for calculating. The difference is just: "c.incorporated='1'  c.zsum_score DESC " and a left join to another scoring table instead of "LEFT JOIN `user_consultants` `c` ON `b`.`user_id`=`c`.`user_id` ".

Comment: @heuri according to your EXPLAIN, it seems that it would be useful to have a **composite** index on `(c.incorporated, c.zsum_score)`

Comment: The `$calculatings` is not optimized this way. Store latitude and longitude as a `GEOMETRY (POINT)` and use a spatial index. Isn't that why you have `cities` as a MyISAM table?

Comment: Yes, before I execute this query I query before for the lat and len by the given postal code. Then I calculate $latitude = $result[0]['lat'] / 180 * M_PI; $longitude = $result[0]['lon'] / 180 * M_PI; and this values I insert in the calculation: 6368 * SQRT(2*(1-cos(RADIANS(`a`.`lat`)) *
cos(" . $latitude . ") * (sin(RADIANS(`a`.`lon`)) *
sin(" . $longitude . ") + cos(RADIANS(`a`.`lon`)) *
cos(" . $longitude . ")) - sin(RADIANS(`a`.`lat`)) * sin(" . $latitude . ")))

Comment: The query may also benefit from adding a compound index in table `users`, on `(typ, activated, banned)`.

Answer (score 2):

I have no time to write full details but to optimize spatial search, here's a quick quide:

Store the `(latitude, longitude)` pair in the (MyISAM) table as a spatial field: `POINT` (a variant of `GEOMETRY` type).

Add a spatial index on this field.

Use the `MBRContains()` or the `MBRWithin()` function in your query, with something like this, that wil use the spatial index to narrow the search inside a square that contains the circle with Radius 25 from your base point:

```
WHERE MBRWithin( cities.myPointField
               , Polygon( @lat-25 @long-25
                        , @lat+25 @long-25
                        , @lat+25 @long+25
                        , @lat-25 @long+25
                        ) 
               )
  AND (yourDistanceCalculation) < 25
```

You can check the MySQL docs: **[Spatial Extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/spatial-extensions.html)**

Comment: But are the distance calculations accurate? Regarding to http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?23,40909,43079  -> Using spatial indexes the calculation was off by around 4km in short range(<100km) distances and off by around 300-400km in long-range distances (>5000km)

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Even in that case though, the aim of using spatial indexes is to narrow the search from the full table to a small percent of the table records.

Answer (score 1):

You should have (at least) indexes on: cities.postal, users.typ, users.activated, users.banned, user_consultants.incorporated

Comment: Thank you, I had already an index on cities.postal, users.typ  and user_consultants.incorporated. I added now an index for users.activated, users.banned too.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    b.user_id,b.firstname,b.lastname,b.address,b.zipcode,b.city,
    ($calculatings) AS Distance
FROM 
    `user_profiles` `b`
    JOIN `users` `u` ON `b`.`user_id`=`u`.`id`
     AND `u`.`typ`=1
     AND `u`.`activated`=1
     AND `u`.`banned`=0
    LEFT JOIN `cities` `a` ON `b`.`zipcode`=`a`.`postal` 
    LEFT JOIN `user_consultants` `c` ON `b`.`user_id`=`c`.`user_id` 
WHERE Distance <= 25
ORDER BY Distance ASC, c.zsum_score DESC
LIMIT 0,30
```

... although, if the value of `$calculatings` is always the same and as I see that it only depends on the data in table `cities` - you should just put another column in it, containing the pre-calculated distance value.

A few notes on the changes I've made:

- I just assume that `typ`, `activated` and `banned` are of type `int` (guessing by the values in your query) - you shouldn't put them in quotes.
- I also assume that since `users` is your main users table, every `user_id` from `user_profiles` should have an existing `id` in `users`, so you don't need `LEFT`.
- `JOIN`s are faster than `WHERE` clauses (and `WHERE` is faster than `HAVING`, as I see another answer that utilizes it).
- As Tudor Constantin has answered - you should take care of indexing all columns that you use as references for join.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going about it slightly off (but could be wrong).  You are starting your query based on the user profiles, but all your criteria are at the lowest level of users and user consultants level.  I would do a STRAIGHT_JOIN (tell optimizer to do in the order YOU declare).  Then, on your joins, doing a LEFT JOIN doesn't necessarily make sense unless you have missing link ID values between the tables which would allow for some records to not have a given city or user profile.  So, that being said, I would put your Users table up front since that would probably have the most restrictive result set via criteria.  In addition, have an index on (typ, activated, banned).  Next, your user_consultants table and have an index on that for (user_id, incorporated).  Cities should have an index on postal, and user_profiles, an index on zipcode.

Here's the final query I would try

```
select STRAIGHT_JOIN
      b.user_id,
      b.firstname,
      b.lastname,
      b.address,
      b.zipcode,
      b.city, 
      ($calculatings) AS Distance
   from 
      (select u.id, c.zsum_score
          from 
             users u
                join user_consultants c
                   on u.id = c.user_id
                  and c.incorporated = '1'
          where
                 u.typ = '1'
             and u.activated = '1'
             and u.banned = '0' ) PreQuery
      join user_profiles b
         on PreQuery.ID = b.user_id
         join cities a on b.zipcode = a.postal
   where
      ($calculatings) <= 25 
   ORDER BY
      Distance ASC, 
      PreQuery.zsum_score DESC 
   LIMIT 30
```

Since the join between user and user consultants was on user ID, then user consultants and user profiles was on user ID, the join between the "PreQuery's" ID is the same thing, so no need to re-join to BOTH tables.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I tried your version: But it took sadly "30 rows in set (1 min 34.27 sec)" to get the result. Explain: http://pastebin.com/xwXHU9b4

Comment: @heuri, That doesn't make ANY sense, almost like the indexes are not thee as I suggested by type, activated, banned on the user table.  Can you retry just "PreQuery" portion of the query, see what THAT results, completely without the rest of the other joins and such.  how many records...  Maybe this query needs to become DISTINCT U.ID, c.ZSum_Score...  Let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The PreQuery just needs 0,218 sec, it seems it depends also much at the distance. With 25 km it needs 8 sek to query, with 400km it took me 653,426 sec. I'm testing now just with 10.000 rows of consultants.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    b.user_id,b.firstname,b.lastname,b.address,b.zipcode,b.city, 
    ($calculatings) AS Distance
FROM 
    `user_profiles` `b`
    JOIN `cities` `a` ON `a`.`postal`=`b`.`zipcode` 
    JOIN `users` `u` ON `b`.`user_id`=`u`.`id` 
    JOIN `user_consultants` `c` ON `b`.`user_id`=`c`.`user_id` 
WHERE     
    c.incorporated='1'  AND 
    u.typ='1' AND 
    u.activated='1' AND 
    u.banned='0' 
HAVING
    Distance <= 25
ORDER BY 
    Distance ASC, c.zsum_score DESC 
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, they query takes sadly still a little long: /* 0 rows affected, 30 rows found. Duration for 1 query: 7,316 sec. */

Comment: @heuri So you want to say that my query is slower that yours? Can you give me an EXPLAIN output of my query? For instance on pastebin.com or somewhere.

Comment: It seems after few test to have the same speed like before, http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/545/sqlm.jpg/